# Why am i getting _Lambda$__2 as the method name using reflection

Tags: .net, reflection

I am using reflection to get the name of a function. Everything was fine and now instead of getting the function name (e.g. SendEmail) i am getting *Lambda$*_2 as the function name.

Nothing seems to have changed in the code that would have changed this.
I have the same behaviour elsewhere in the project and that still works fine.

My code:

```
Private _sendEmailDel As Zeta.Bol.SendEmailDel (this is a delegate sub)

_sendEmailDel = AddressOf Zeta.Bol.SendEmail

dim methName as string = _sendEmailDel.Method.Name
```

Zeta.Bol.SendEmail is normal function (no lambda involved).

Answer (score 4):

That's because you're trying to get the name of your delegate, not the original function. Since you declared the delegate anonymously, the compiler generates an automatic name for it.